# How do I rotate individual letters of an image into the right orientation for optimal OCR?

Tags: c#, tesseract, aforge

In [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41731626), I transformed this image:

[image]

into this:

[image]

which Tesseract OCR interprets as this:

```
1O351
```

Putting a frame around the image

[image]

actually improves the OCR result.

```
 1CB51
```

However, I need all 5 characters to OCR correctly, so as an experiment I used Paint.NET to rotate and align each individual letter into its proper orientation:

[image]

Resulting in the correct answer:

```
1CB52
```

How would I go about performing this correction in C#?

I've done a bit of research on various text alignment algorithms, but they all assume the existence of *lines of text* in the source image, lines from which you can derive a rotation angle, but which already contain the proper spacing and orientation relationships between the letters.

Comment: You could find all of the individual letters and seperate them off and rotate them all individually

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much the general description of what I need to accomplish in actual code.  I already know *what* I need to do; now I just need to figure out *how* to do it.

Comment: It appears you're trying to break a CAPTCHA. Even if you succeed, there are now other types of CAPTCHA that won't be so easy to crack, such as the "I'm not a robot" reCAPTCHA system from Google, or even [text-based systems like those shown in this forum](https://www.leadtools.com/support/forum/posts/t10685-HOWTO--Generate-CAPTCHA-using-LEAD-image-processing-functions).

Comment: A note about putting the frame around the image, if tesseract does auto pre-processing the lines of the box probably stop it from doing it on the characters and resulting in awkward deskewing seeing as they are all at different angles. It also helps to tell the engine where the characters are.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the code in the following [code project article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/336915/Connected-Component-Labeling-Algorithm) to segment each individual character. However, when trying to deskew these characters individually any result you get is not going to be very good because there isn't very much information to go off of.

I tried using `AForge.NET`s [`HoughLineTransformation` class](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/aa234a78-bc23-c0a8-4a36-33aba5c75d9c.htm) and I got angles in the range of 80 - 90 degrees. So I tried using the following code to deskew them:

```
private static Bitmap DeskewImageByIndividualChars(Bitmap targetBitmap)
{
    IDictionary<Rectangle, Bitmap> characters = new CCL().Process(targetBitmap);

    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(targetBitmap))
    {
        foreach (var character in characters)
        {
            double angle;

            BitmapData bitmapData = character.Value.LockBits(new Rectangle(Point.Empty, character.Value.Size), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
            try
            {
                HoughLineTransformation hlt = new HoughLineTransformation();
                hlt.ProcessImage(bitmapData);

                angle = hlt.GetLinesByRelativeIntensity(0.5).Average(l => l.Theta);
            }
            finally
            {
                character.Value.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
            }

            using (Bitmap bitmap = RotateImage(character.Value, 90 - angle, Color.White))
            {
                g.DrawImage(bitmap, character.Key.Location);
            }
        }
    }

    return targetBitmap;
}
```

With the [`RotateImage` method taken from here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184700/how-to-rotate-image-x-degrees-in-c) However, the results didn't seem to be the best. Maybe you can try and make them better.

Here is the code from the code project article for your reference. I have made a few changes to it so that it behaves a bit safer, such as adding `try-finally` around the `LockBits` and disposing of objects properly using the `using` statement etc.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConnectedComponentLabeling
{
    public class CCL
    {
        private Bitmap _input;
        private int[,] _board;

        public IDictionary<Rectangle, Bitmap> Process(Bitmap input)
        {
            _input = input;
            _board = new int[_input.Width, _input.Height];

            Dictionary<int, List<Pixel>> patterns = Find();
            var images = new Dictionary<Rectangle, Bitmap>();

            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, List<Pixel>> pattern in patterns)
            {
                using (Bitmap bmp = CreateBitmap(pattern.Value))
                {
                    images.Add(GetBounds(pattern.Value), (Bitmap)bmp.Clone());
                }
            }

            return images;
        }

        protected virtual bool CheckIsBackGround(Pixel currentPixel)
        {
            return currentPixel.color.A == 255 && currentPixel.color.R == 255 && currentPixel.color.G == 255 && currentPixel.color.B == 255;
        }

        private unsafe Dictionary<int, List<Pixel>> Find()
        {
            int labelCount = 1;
            var allLabels = new Dictionary<int, Label>();

            BitmapData imageData = _input.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, _input.Width, _input.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            try
            {
                int bytesPerPixel = 3;

                byte* scan0 = (byte*)imageData.Scan0.ToPointer();
                int stride = imageData.Stride;

                for (int i = 0; i < _input.Height; i++)
                {
                    byte* row = scan0 + (i * stride);

                    for (int j = 0; j < _input.Width; j++)
                    {
                        int bIndex = j * bytesPerPixel;
                        int gIndex = bIndex + 1;
                        int rIndex = bIndex + 2;

                        byte pixelR = row[rIndex];
                        byte pixelG = row[gIndex];
                        byte pixelB = row[bIndex];

                        Pixel currentPixel = new Pixel(new Point(j, i), Color.FromArgb(pixelR, pixelG, pixelB));

                        if (CheckIsBackGround(currentPixel))
                        {
                            continue;
                        }

                        IEnumerable<int> neighboringLabels = GetNeighboringLabels(currentPixel);
                        int currentLabel;

                        if (!neighboringLabels.Any())
                        {
                            currentLabel = labelCount;
                            allLabels.Add(currentLabel, new Label(currentLabel));
                            labelCount++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            currentLabel = neighboringLabels.Min(n => allLabels[n].GetRoot().Name);
                            Label root = allLabels[currentLabel].GetRoot();

                            foreach (var neighbor in neighboringLabels)
                            {
                                if (root.Name != allLabels[neighbor].GetRoot().Name)
                                {
                                    allLabels[neighbor].Join(allLabels[currentLabel]);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        _board[j, i] = currentLabel;
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                _input.UnlockBits(imageData);
            }

            Dictionary<int, List<Pixel>> patterns = AggregatePatterns(allLabels);

            patterns = RemoveIntrusions(patterns, _input.Width, _input.Height);

            return patterns;
        }

        private Dictionary<int, List<Pixel>> RemoveIntrusions(Dictionary<int, List<Pixel>> patterns, int width, int height)
        {
            var patternsCleaned = new Dictionary<int, List<Pixel>>();

            foreach (var pattern in patterns)
            {
                bool bad = false;
                foreach (Pixel item in pattern.Value)
                {
                    //Horiz
                    if (item.Position.X == 0)
                        bad = true;

                    else if (item.Position.Y == width - 1)
                        bad = true;

                    //Vert
                    else if (item.Position.Y == 0)
                        bad = true;

                    else if (item.Position.Y == height - 1)
                        bad = true;
                }

                if (!bad)
                    patternsCleaned.Add(pattern.Key, pattern.Value);

            }

            return patternsCleaned;
        }

        private IEnumerable<int> GetNeighboringLabels(Pixel pix)
        {
            var neighboringLabels = new List<int>();

            for (int i = pix.Position.Y - 1; i <= pix.Position.Y + 2 && i < _input.Height - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = pix.Position.X - 1; j <= pix.Position.X + 2 && j < _input.Width - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (i > -1 && j > -1 && _board[j, i] != 0)
                    {
                        neighboringLabels.Add(_board[j, i]);
                    }
                }
            }

            return neighboringLabels;
        }

        private Dictionary<int, List<Pixel>> AggregatePatterns(Dictionary<int, Label> allLabels)
        {
            var patterns = new Dictionary<int, List<Pixel>>();

            for (int i = 0; i < _input.Height; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < _input.Width; j++)
                {
                    int patternNumber = _board[j, i];
                    if (patternNumber != 0)
                    {
                        patternNumber = allLabels[patternNumber].GetRoot().Name;

                        if (!patterns.ContainsKey(patternNumber))
                        {
                            patterns[patternNumber] = new List<Pixel>();
                        }

                        patterns[patternNumber].Add(new Pixel(new Point(j, i), Color.Black));
                    }
                }
            }

            return patterns;
        }

        private unsafe Bitmap CreateBitmap(List<Pixel> pattern)
        {
            int minX = pattern.Min(p => p.Position.X);
            int maxX = pattern.Max(p => p.Position.X);

            int minY = pattern.Min(p => p.Position.Y);
            int maxY = pattern.Max(p => p.Position.Y);

            int width = maxX + 1 - minX;
            int height = maxY + 1 - minY;

            Bitmap bmp = DrawFilledRectangle(width, height);

            BitmapData imageData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            try
            {
                byte* scan0 = (byte*)imageData.Scan0.ToPointer();
                int stride = imageData.Stride;

                foreach (Pixel pix in pattern)
                {
                    scan0[((pix.Position.X - minX) * 3) + (pix.Position.Y - minY) * stride] = pix.color.B;
                    scan0[((pix.Position.X - minX) * 3) + (pix.Position.Y - minY) * stride + 1] = pix.color.G;
                    scan0[((pix.Position.X - minX) * 3) + (pix.Position.Y - minY) * stride + 2] = pix.color.R;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                bmp.UnlockBits(imageData);
            }

            return bmp;
        }

        private Bitmap DrawFilledRectangle(int x, int y)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(x, y);
            using (Graphics graph = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                Rectangle ImageSize = new Rectangle(0, 0, x, y);
                graph.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, ImageSize);
            }

            return bmp;
        }

        private Rectangle GetBounds(List<Pixel> pattern)
        {
            var points = pattern.Select(x => x.Position);

            var x_query = points.Select(p => p.X);
            int xmin = x_query.Min();
            int xmax = x_query.Max();

            var y_query = points.Select(p => p.Y);
            int ymin = y_query.Min();
            int ymax = y_query.Max();

            return new Rectangle(xmin, ymin, xmax - xmin, ymax - ymin);
        }
    }
}
```

With the above code I got the following input/output:

[image: Input] [image: Output]

As you can see the `B` has rotated quite well but the others aren't as good.

---

An alternative to trying to deskew the individual characters is to find there location using the segmentation routine above. Then passing each individual character through to your recognition engine separately and seeing if this improves your results.

---

I have used the following method to find the angle of the character using the `List<Pixel>` from inside the `CCL` class. It works by finding the angle between the "bottom left" and "bottom right" points. I haven't tested if it works if the character is rotated the other way around.

```
private double GetAngle(List<Pixel> pattern)
{
    var pixels = pattern.Select(p => p.Position).ToArray();

    Point bottomLeft = pixels.OrderByDescending(p => p.Y).ThenBy(p => p.X).First();
    Point rightBottom = pixels.OrderByDescending(p => p.X).ThenByDescending(p => p.Y).First();

    int xDiff = rightBottom.X - bottomLeft.X;
    int yDiff = rightBottom.Y - bottomLeft.Y;

    double angle = Math.Atan2(yDiff, xDiff) * 180 / Math.PI;

    return -angle;
}
```

Note my drawing code is a bit broken so that is why the `5` is cut off on the right but this code produces the following output:

[image: Output]

Note that the `B` and the `5` are rotated further than you'd expect because of their curvature.

---

Using the following code by getting the angle from the left and right edges and then choosing the best one, the rotations seems to be better. Note I have only tested it with letters that need rotating clockwise so if they need to go the opposite way it might not work too well.

This also "quadrants" the pixels so that each pixel is chosen from it's own quadrant as not to get two that are too nearby.

The idea in selecting the best angle is if they are similar, at the moment within 1.5 degrees of each other but can easily be updated, average them. Else we pick the one that is closest to zero.

```
private double GetAngle(List<Pixel> pattern, Rectangle bounds)
{
    int halfWidth = bounds.X + (bounds.Width / 2);
    int halfHeight = bounds.Y + (bounds.Height / 2);

    double leftEdgeAngle = GetAngleLeftEdge(pattern, halfWidth, halfHeight);
    double rightEdgeAngle = GetAngleRightEdge(pattern, halfWidth, halfHeight);

    if (Math.Abs(leftEdgeAngle - rightEdgeAngle) <= 1.5)
    {
        return (leftEdgeAngle + rightEdgeAngle) / 2d;
    }

    if (Math.Abs(leftEdgeAngle) > Math.Abs(rightEdgeAngle))
    {
        return rightEdgeAngle;
    }
    else
    {
        return leftEdgeAngle;
    }
}

private double GetAngleLeftEdge(List<Pixel> pattern, double halfWidth, double halfHeight)
{
    var topLeftPixels = pattern.Select(p => p.Position).Where(p => p.Y < halfHeight && p.X < halfWidth).ToArray();
    var bottomLeftPixels = pattern.Select(p => p.Position).Where(p => p.Y > halfHeight && p.X < halfWidth).ToArray();

    Point topLeft = topLeftPixels.OrderBy(p => p.X).ThenBy(p => p.Y).First();
    Point bottomLeft = bottomLeftPixels.OrderByDescending(p => p.Y).ThenBy(p => p.X).First();

    int xDiff = bottomLeft.X - topLeft.X;
    int yDiff = bottomLeft.Y - topLeft.Y;

    double angle = Math.Atan2(yDiff, xDiff) * 180 / Math.PI;

    return 90 - angle;
}

private double GetAngleRightEdge(List<Pixel> pattern, double halfWidth, double halfHeight)
{
    var topRightPixels = pattern.Select(p => p.Position).Where(p => p.Y < halfHeight && p.X > halfWidth).ToArray();
    var bottomRightPixels = pattern.Select(p => p.Position).Where(p => p.Y > halfHeight && p.X > halfWidth).ToArray();

    Point topRight = topRightPixels.OrderBy(p => p.Y).ThenByDescending(p => p.X).First();
    Point bottomRight = bottomRightPixels.OrderByDescending(p => p.X).ThenByDescending(p => p.Y).First();

    int xDiff = bottomRight.X - topRight.X;
    int yDiff = bottomRight.Y - topRight.Y;

    double angle = Math.Atan2(xDiff, yDiff) * 180 / Math.PI;

    return Math.Abs(angle);
}
```

This now produces the following output, again my drawing code is slightly broken. Note that the `C` looks to not have deskewed very well but looking closely it is just the shape of it that has caused this to happen.

[image: Output]

---

I improved the drawing code and also attempted to get the characters onto the same baseline:

```
private static Bitmap DeskewImageByIndividualChars(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    IDictionary<Rectangle, Tuple<Bitmap, double>> characters = new CCL().Process(bitmap);

    Bitmap deskewedBitmap = new Bitmap(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height, bitmap.PixelFormat);
    deskewedBitmap.SetResolution(bitmap.HorizontalResolution, bitmap.VerticalResolution);

    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(deskewedBitmap))
    {
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, deskewedBitmap.Size));

        int baseLine = characters.Max(c => c.Key.Bottom);
        foreach (var character in characters)
        {
            int y = character.Key.Y;
            if (character.Key.Bottom != baseLine)
            {
                y += (baseLine - character.Key.Bottom - 1);
            }

            using (Bitmap characterBitmap = RotateImage(character.Value.Item1, character.Value.Item2, Color.White))
            {
                g.DrawImage(characterBitmap, new Point(character.Key.X, y));
            }
        }
    }

    return deskewedBitmap;
}
```

This then produces the following output. Note each character isn't on the exact same baseline due to the pre rotation bottom being taken to work it out. To improve the code using the baseline from post rotation would be needed. Also thresholding the image before doing the baseline would help.

Another improvement would be to calculate the `Right` of each of the rotated characters locations so when drawing the next one it doesn't overlap the previous and cut bits off. Because as you can see in the output the `2` is slightly cutting into the `5`.

The output is now very similar to the manually created one in the OP.

[image: Output]

Comment: Thanks for this.  Note that you'll get better results by using the top left and bottom left points to rotate.  For the C it's actually the top right and bottom right.  I'm still trying to figure out how to choose the best set of points.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I only wrote some quick code to show the idea as I'm at work so don't have that much time to look at it. You could always work out all of the points and angles and average them, whilst removing extremes although that is more of a brute force than clever solution.

Comment: I appreciate your time.  Historically I've given bounties to those who've worked on problems I've posted.  I plan to do the same here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Oh nice! If I get some time I will try and work on the rotation stuff some more but looks like you've got a handle on that now.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've made some further improvements to the deskewing code

Comment: @RobertHarvey I attempted to get all of the characters onto the same baseline and the output now looks very similar to your manually created one. Although there are still improvements to be made that I have mentioned in the post.

Comment: This is great stuff.  As you suspected, the rotation only works with letters that lean to the left.  Unfortunately my Trigonometry class took place so long ago that I haven't quite worked out the bug yet, but thanks.

Comment: @Robert I think the main problem is the pixels it selects. Try and output the points from the get angle methods to see what comes out.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The code that rotates the character is what is causing them to chop off others because it adds a lot of whitespace around them

Comment: Have you tried this with the number `4`? I believe it won't work as expected, because TL and BL are not in a streight line.

Comment: @cansik I have not but then this is only sample code to show the idea. If you want it to work a lot better there's more cases than just a `4` that you'd have to look at fixing.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Yes, I was just interested because I am working on the same problem at the moment.

Comment: @cansik I did have a bit of fun playing with it when I worked on the answer so maybe I'll dig the code out and give it a go at some point. However, the main thing to fix is pretty much just the angle detection logic as far as I can see.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Is it possible for you to create a git repository of your source code?

Comment: @NishithShah Unfortunately, it looks like I've deleted or lost the code to this at some point over the years. You should be able to recreate it from the code here though. I believe everything is here that needs to be.